# Bootstrap 3: Fitting video to grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple videos that I would like to be resized to it's parent bootstrap div in a grid format but the weird thing is that it's increasing the size of the col but not the video itself.

Here is a sample of how the code goes in the grid format. In my CSS file, the class gif-video width and height is both set to 300.

Here is an [image](http://puu.sh/kBtVv/19075aed4b.png) representing my problem.

If i change the gif-video width and height to 100%, here is how it looks like. The size is correct but there are empty spaces as though the div got pushed down.

Here is an [image](http://puu.sh/kBu5D/314eba8ac5.png) representing this issue.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <video class="gif-video" autoplay loop poster="http://thumbs.gfycat.com/<%= title %>.jpg">     
                    <source src=<%= gif.webmurl %> type="video/webm">
                    <source src=<%= gif.mp4url %> type="video/mp4">
                </video>  
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The videos have raspect ratio attach to them (16/9, 4/3, etc...) So your container/grid shoud have the same aspect ratio to feet.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to bootstrap but how do I set them to have the same aspect ratio? When I refresh the page before the video is loaded, they have the correct layout but when the video is rendered the grid is bugged.

Comment: Read this, maybe it help you - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

Answer (score 0):

Set max-height and max-width to div , some of video must been little bit bigger and maybe push paddings to right or bottom

Comment: Where do I set that under? Do I just set them both to 100%? I noticed that when I refresh the page, the layout is exactly what I wanted but when the page loaded, it gets pushed down.